# MS SQL Query a field containing JSON

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-json

I have the following JSON in a SQL field in a table:

```
{
   "type": "info",
   "date": "2019/11/12 14:28:51",
    "state": {
        "6ee8587f-3b8c-4e5c-89a9-9f04752607f0": {
            "state": "open",
            "color": "#0000ff"
        }
    },
...
}
```

I query this in MS SQL using the folloing:

```
SELECT 
     JSON_VALUE(json_data, '$.type') AS msg_type
    ,JSON_VALUE(json_data, '$."date"') AS event_date
    ,JSON_QUERY(json_data, '$.state."6ee8587f-3b8c-4e5c-89a9-9f04752607f0".state') AS json_state
    ,JSON_QUERY(json_data, '$.state."6ee8587f-3b8c-4e5c-89a9-9f04752607f0".color') AS json_color
FROM 
[dbo].[tbl_json_dump]
```

To get the date (a reserved word) back I have to put the the field name in like $."date"

I cannot seem to get the data back for the state or color fields and I think it has to do with that it is nested under "6ee8587f-3b8c-4e5c-89a9-9f04752607f0" because when I query :

```
JSON_QUERY(json_data, '$.state."6ee8587f-3b8c-4e5c-89a9-9f04752607f0"') AS json_state
```

I get the object back -

```
{"state":"open","color":"#0000ff"}
```

but using

```
JSON_QUERY(json_data, '$.state."6ee8587f-3b8c-4e5c-89a9-9f04752607f0".state') AS json_state
```

it is not working

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `JSON_QUERY` with `JSON_VALUE` since you're interested in getting the value.

---

`JSON_QUERY` is supposed to return a JSON fragment and designed to work on objects and arrays, not values.

Comment: Thank you for spotting the mistake... Fresh eyes on the issue always helps!!

Answer (score 1):

You may try with another possible approach (more complicated), which parses all nested JSON objects.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   JsonData nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO Data
   (JsonData)
VALUES 
   (N'{
   "type": "info",
   "date": "2019/11/12 14:28:51",
    "state": {
        "6ee8587f-3b8c-4e5c-89a9-9f04752607f0": {
            "state": "open",
            "color": "#0000ff"
        },
        "6ee8587f-3b8c-4e5c-89a9-9f04752607f1": {
            "state": "open",
            "color": "#0000ff"
        }
    }
}')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   j1.[type], j1.[date], j2.[key], j3.state, j3.color
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.JsonData) WITH (
   [type] nvarchar(100) '$.type',
   [date] datetime '$.date',
   [state] nvarchar(max) '$.state' AS JSON
) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.state) j2
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j2.[value]) WITH (
   state nvarchar(10) '$.state',
   color nvarchar(10) '$.color'
) j3
```

Result:

```
type    date                key                                     state   color
info    12/11/2019 14:28:51 6ee8587f-3b8c-4e5c-89a9-9f04752607f0    open    #0000ff
info    12/11/2019 14:28:51 6ee8587f-3b8c-4e5c-89a9-9f04752607f1    open    #0000ff
```

Notes:

If the input `JSON` has only one key `"6ee8587f-3b8c-4e5c-89a9-9f04752607f0"` in the `"state"` `JSON` object, you may get the value with `JSON_VALUE()` using the correct path `$.state."6ee8587f-3b8c-4e5c-89a9-9f04752607f0".state`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment... I will have a look at using your method in a other query I have to transpose data into a table

Answer (score 1):

Salman A already provided the answer. Just to add a few points.

`JSON_VALUE()` - Extracts a Scalar value

`JSON_QUERY()` - Extracts an object or an array from a JSON string.

If you see the syntax , `JSON_QUERY ( expression [ , path ] )` & `JSON_VALUE ( expression , path )` , both are more or less except the `[]` square brackets for `path` and it means optional. It is because `JSON_QUERY()` can extract whole JSON field if required.

And on the return types,

`JSON_VALUE()` returns a JSON fragment of type `nvarchar(max)`

`JSON_QUERY()` returns a single text value of type `nvarchar(4000)`

**Overall comparison**

```
DECLARE @data NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @data=N'{
    "type": "info",
   "date": "2019/11/12 14:28:51",
    "state": {
        "6ee8587f-3b8c-4e5c-89a9-9f04752607f0": {
            "state": "open",
            "color": "#0000ff"
        }
    },
}'
 SELECT 
   JSON_VALUE(@data,'$.state."6ee8587f-3b8c-4e5c-89a9-9f04752607f0"') AS 'JSON_VALUE_FAILED',
   JSON_QUERY(@data,'$.state."6ee8587f-3b8c-4e5c-89a9-9f04752607f0"') AS 'JSON_QUERY_SUCCEED',
   JSON_VALUE(@data,'$.state."6ee8587f-3b8c-4e5c-89a9-9f04752607f0".state') AS 'JSON_VALUE_SUCCEED',
   JSON_QUERY(@data,'$.state."6ee8587f-3b8c-4e5c-89a9-9f04752607f0".state') AS 'JSON_QUERY_SUCCEED';
```

[**Check Output here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a579dcc8b5dcfbbf4f6bfb588da15841)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment... As you rightfully said Salman A was able to spot my mistake, but I appreciate the valuable input. This will definitely help someone else when they search for info on MSSQL/JSON queries!